# SQL Subquery assistance. Simple Code is giving error message

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a query that will display the name, dep no. , and all the workers that work in the same dep as a specific person. I have written some code for it but its giving an error.

```
SELECT d.deptno ,d.ename , e.ename
FROM   emp e, emp d
WHERE  deptno = ( SELECT  DISTINCT deptno
                  from emp
                  WHERE  d.deptno = e.deptno );
```

Cheers

-Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT d.deptno AS DEPARTMENT,d.ename AS EMPLOYEE , e.ename AS COLLEAGUE
FROM   emp e, emp d
WHERE  d.deptno = e.deptno AND d.ename <> e.ename;
```